# Deleting NSURLCredential permanently?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I am trying to delete a NSURLCredential that is written when I access a secure HTTP site. The code below works and deletes the `NSURLCredential` from `NSURLCredentialStorage`, but even though I am specifying that:

```
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData timeoutInterval:60];
```

does not reload cached data and I have implemented the method:

```
- (NSCachedURLResponse *)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection willCacheResponse:(NSCachedURLResponse *)cachedResponse {
    return nil;
}
```

the next time I run the application deleteStoredCredential finds a new credential for "loginSiteName.com" and deletes it. My question is, am I missing something, is there anywhere else I need to clear, could the credential be cached on the iPhone?

```
-(void)deleteStoredCredential {
    NSURLCredentialStorage *sharedCredentialStorage = [NSURLCredentialStorage sharedCredentialStorage];
    NSDictionary *DICT_allProtectionSpaces = [sharedCredentialStorage allCredentials];
    // DICT KEY   = NSURLProtectionSpace
    // DICT VALUE = NSDictionary

    for(NSURLProtectionSpace *thisProtectionSpace in DICT_allProtectionSpaces) {
        if([[thisProtectionSpace host] isEqualToString:@"loginSiteName.com"]) {
            NSDictionary *DICT_allCredentials = [sharedCredentialStorage credentialsForProtectionSpace:thisProtectionSpace];
            // DICT KEY   = NSString (i.e. username)
            // DICT VALUE = NSURLCredential

            for(NSString *thisUserName in DICT_allCredentials) {
                NSURLCredential *credentialToDelete = [DICT_allCredentials valueForKey:thisUserName];
                NSLog(@"REMOVE UID: %@ WITH PWD: %@", [credentialToDelete user], [credentialToDelete password]);
                [sharedCredentialStorage removeCredential:credentialToDelete forProtectionSpace:thisProtectionSpace];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the problem: the `NSURLCredential` that I create to access the site was created with `NSURLCredentialPersistencePermanent` instead of `NSURLCredentialPersistenceNone`. As a consequence the credential was getting stored in the iPhone keychain.

Comment: Do you perhaps know how one could delete that credential from the keychain?

Comment: I am also running into the same problem.  I did set NSURLCredentialPersistenceNone on the credential.  Something is still cached.

Answer (score 0):

i use also NSURLCredentialPersistenceNone to avoid to store the credential in the storage.
But i remark that i need to wait some seconde like 10 sec to clear the old credential and then start the new credential SSL certificat client.

Have u remark this strange behavior in NSURLConnection class ?

Thanks for you help :)